# How can I call REXML::Element::add_attributes from a chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm having some 'chef != ruby' issues. I have some XML code that seems to work fine in `irb` and `pry`, but fails in chef with an

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `add_attribute'
```

error.

```
require "rexml/document"
::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, REXML) # can't `include REXML`
updates = Document.new(File.new updates_file)
options = updates.elements.each('application/component/option[@name="CHECK_NEEDED"]/@value') {|e| e}
unless options.empty?
  # Set existing <option /> Element
  element = options[0]
#  element.add_attribute("value", "false")
#  element.add_attribute( Attribute.new("value", "false") )
#  element.send("add_attribute", "value", "false")
  element.send("add_attribute", Attribute.new("value", "false"))
```

How can I get this recipe to "compile"?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want this code in recipe instead of library? Also, you may like to refer:- https://blog.chef.io/2013/09/04/demystifying-common-idioms-in-chef-recipes/

Comment: So you're melting namespaces with a likely method name collision, why not just using REXML::<method> ? (and avoiding the Recipe.send call)

Comment: Oh, sigh. Problem was actually in the `updates.elements.each('application/component/option[@name="CHECK_NEEDED"]/@value') {|e| e}`, which was returning an REXML::Attribute, not the REXML::Element that contains it.